# html5 canvas stroke color always displaying as grey?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got an array like this:

```
var hitColors = ["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff","#ffff00","#00ffff","#ff00ff"];
```

I've got a canvas that I'm "redrawing" every few seconds like this:

```
// main canvas rectangle
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

context.rect(thisXPos-1, thisYPos-1, words[activeWord][2].width+2, words[activeWord][2].height+2);
context.strokeStyle = hitColors[hitSpot];

alert('"' + hitColors[hitSpot] + '"');
alert(context.strokeStyle);

context.lineWidth = 1;
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

I can confirm that context.closePath(); is returning the proper color from the array but when I alert context.StrokeStyle it's always set to #000000 and the rect border is grey.  How can I fix this?

Comment: part of an IF statement around that piece of code, let me edit and clean it up

Comment: If you want a more detailed analysis you should post your code or a working prototype on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched the array to this:

```
var hitColors = ["#f00","#0f0","#00f","#ff0","#0ff","#f0f"];
```

and it started working properly.

Comment: Alright, I was wrong :P, but it's still something you should keep in mind when drawing 1 pixel wide lines.

Comment: +1 for posting solution :) Though I'm not sure how that fixes it.

Comment: I appreciate the link, I upvoted your comment.  It just didn't happen to fix this particular issue.  I'm not sure why the shorter hex works either, I saw a sample on another site using the abbreviated version and tried it on a whim.  Just wanted to post it in case someone else experiences the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Add or subtract 0.5 pixels from your values.

Basically, if you try to draw a 1px line centered around an integer pixel value what you end up with is a 2 pixel line centered around that point which and the line will be semi-transparent. Semi-transparent black looks like grey. So, if you want a straight line of any colour that is exactly 1 pixel wide, you need to draw that line with at pixel intervals of 0.5.

Comment: What does that have to do with the color?  I'm not worried about the line width.

Comment: It's a bit of a guess, but if you try to draw a 1px line centered around an integer pixel value what you end up with is a 2 pixel line centered around that point which is semi-transparent. Semi-transparent (alpha < 1) black = grey.

Answer (score 1):

You never set you strokeStyle. its defaulting to #000000.